# Multiple TextSwitcher on single activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to place 3 TextSwitcher in single Activity one after the other.
The problem is that only first textswitcher works OK. the rest of them show nothing. Also no exceptions was thrown. When I remove the first one the second starts to works fine. I make assumption that only one TextSwitcher can exists in single activity but I cannot find confirmation about this. Or maybe I do something wrong as I am new in Android world.
This is part of my view:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textSwitcher1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextSwitcher>
        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textSwitcher2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextSwitcher>
        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textSwitcher3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextSwitcher>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

To setup the TextSwitcher I created following method:

```
private TextSwitcher InitializeTextSwitcher(int textSwitcherId) {
    TextSwitcher ts = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(textSwitcherId);

    ts.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            TextView myText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            myText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            myText.setTextSize(48);
            myText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            return myText;
        }
    });

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    ts.setInAnimation(in);
    ts.setOutAnimation(out);

    return ts;
}
```

At the end I use Runnable object + Handler to schedule text changes:

```
    Runnable r=new Runnable() {
    // Override the run Method
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            if(timeElapsed == timeStep) {
                textSwitcher1.setText(textToShow[0]);
            }else if (timeElapsed == 2*timeStep){
                textSwitcher2.setText(textToShow[1]);
            }else if(timeElapsed == 3*timeStep){
                textSwitcher3.setText(textToShow[2]);
            }else if (timeElapsed == 4*timeStep){
                 //Do something else
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            timeElapsed += timeStep;
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, timeStep);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that, due to the way your layout is setup, you're only actually seeing one `TextSwitcher` at a time, which explains why the second one starts working when you remove the first.

Assuming you want the `TextSwitcher`s all on one horizontal line, one possible layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/textSwitcher1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextSwitcher>
    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/textSwitcher2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextSwitcher>
    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/textSwitcher3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextSwitcher>
</LinearLayout>
```